# What's the difference between not and ~ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just to check, I couldn't find anything about ~, so I want to make sure it's the same.

Also, can you use ! in python like in C++?

It seems that these two codes give the same output:

```
bool(~0)
```

```
bool(not 0)
```

Comment: Try it without `bool()` to see the difference…?

Comment: `not` evaluates its operand as bool and negates it. `~` generally is a "bitwise not", but what exactly it does depends on each type.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is answered by the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html).

Comment: `print(  (not 8) + (not 7) ,"vs", (~ 8) + (~ 7))   => `0 vs -18` - does not seem to be the same.  Arguing from 1 thing where it is same leaves out an nearly unlimited amout of testcases that may not be same.

Comment: I searched for "~" and couldn't find anything :/

Comment: Hint: https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-Symbols.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it is in Python.

> '~' is a bitwise operator
>
> whereas 'not' is a logical opeartor

Comment: Refer this to learn about operators => https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Comment: Refer to ***[this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)*** to learn about operators. W3S is not exactly the premier reference.

Comment: I agree with that @deceze

Comment: I referenced W3S because it has an example and an editor to test the example. OP seems to be a beginner. @deceze

Answer (score 0):

You should read [`Python 3.10 documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) at `Unary arithmetic and bitwise operations`.

---

The `~` operator does a simple job:

> Inverts the bits